# Релевантный поиск похожих записей в базе данных

Tags: sql, поиск

Имеется набор записей в БД (тип недвижимости, город, район, цена и т.д), разнесённый в несколько связанных между собою таблиц(недвижимость, адреса, (квартиры, участки, и т.д.)). Нужно вывести записи, похожие на выбранную (можно передать её в запросе целиком, или её id(первичный ключ)). Желательно присвоить полям веса, и на основе сравнения их с шаблоном, плюсовать записям значения от нуля до веса поля (100% совпадение), и, затем, отсортировать записи от самых "тяжёлых", до "лёгких". Поля текстовые и числовые.

Возможно ли реализовать эту задачу средствами SQL, и, если да, пожалуйста, подскажите как или где прочитать об этом подробнее?

P.S. У записей есть web-представление (страница информации о конкретном варианте недвижимости) с постоянным адресом формата http://mysite.ru/info/id. Возможно ли использовать поисковики (google, yandex и т.д.) для нахождения похожих вариантов? Я нашёл только вариант с простым добавлением полнотекстового поиска на сайт, но, возможно, существуют и более подходящие инструменты?

Comment: Да, решить можно. А как, зависит от конкретной задачи, описания, что такое "похоже" для каждого конкретного поля в отдельности. и от того какой диалект sql используется, конечно то же зависит. Если простое совпадение полей - то все просто умножаете веса на факт совпало или нет. А для разницы в текстах можно применять полнотекстовый поиск или например soundex

Comment: На данный момент для цены "похоже" - это +-200 000, для остальных - совпало/не совпало, но требования могут изменится. А вот увидеть бы шаблон запроса, где и как прописывать критерии для "похоже" очень бы хотелось, как и ссылку, где бы о таком поискать. Гугл только LIKE и MATCH (`поле`) AGAINST ('поисковая фраза') находит, без никаких пояснений, что, почему, куда и как

Comment: Значит надо систематизировать требования. сделать например таблицу настроек в которой допустимый диапазон задавать (для числовых полей), который по умолчанию от 0 до 0 - т.е. полное совпадение. и веса в той же таблице могут быть. конечно для текстовых полей все сложнее. тут действительно надо смотреть что match какой нибудь возвращает. И еще структуру БД надо будет приводить буквально к формату ключ-значение что бы единым запросом все виды параметров сравнивать ...